# How to open and read text file in JavaScript asynchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm attempting to open and read a text file in JavaScript without using any direct HTML, just JavaSCript.  However, because JavaScript is asynchronous the function is finished executing before i can select the file to read.  Is there a callback function i can use to read the file only after i've selected it? I don't know why the code continues to execute before i've finished selecting my file. I can now get my file opened and read but i still cannot return the built text object. Here's the code i currently have:

```
        loadFileFromDisk: function (leaveHere) {
        var openFile = this.createElement("INPUT");
        openFile.setAttribute("type", "file");
        openFile.setAttribute("id", "openFile");
        var openElement = document.getElementById("openFile");

        openElement.addEventListener("change",
            function(changeEvent) {
                var selectedFile = changeEvent.target.files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    var text = reader.result;
                    leaveHere(text);
                };
                reader.readAsText(selectedFile);
            }
        );

        openFile.click();

    };
```

Comment: Well, you need to wait for the `change` event on the input… you cannot directly `return` the result.

Comment: No. `click` does not take a callback. Use `openFile.addEventListener('change', …)`

Comment: You [cannot `return` from an asynchronous function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1048572) at all. Use a callback or promises.

Comment: As a parameter to `loadFileFromDisk`. Then, instead of trying to `return text;`, call `callback(text);`. And of course you'll have to change how you are invoking the method everywhere.